# How to handle exceptions from failed xUnit tests?

Tags: xunit, xunit.net

I want to handle exceptions from failed `xUnit` tests to save exception details to my generated html report.

I guess I have to add this feature to my custom test framework (inherited from `XunitTestFramework`) but where should I put `try/catch` block?

Comment: Do you mean that the code under test throws? the assertion in the test?

Comment: No, I write automated selenium tests and I don't use assertions in general. My tests can throw exception everywhere so I want to catch it and save to report.